# Debugging Magento 2.4 on windows

Tags: magento2.4, windows, phpstorm, xdebug, windows10

Here is the setup:

- Magento 2.4 up and running
- Windows 10 & Xampp
- Php 7.3.25
- Xdebug enabled.Below is php.ini configuration, xdebug section

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = "C:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"

xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

However when I run the magento - it keeps spinning endlessly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below configuration in **php.ini** file,

```
    [XDebug]
    zend_extension=xdebug
    xdebug.remote_autostart=1
    xdebug.default_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
    xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
    xdebug.remote_enable =1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
    xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
```

And create the new **idekey** name with **PHPSTORM**